# ArrayList throw outOfIndex when adds a element

Tags: java, arraylist

**adding a raw element like ar1.add(0) is ok not throw error but when trying to add ar1.add(s) throw error**
**the error is not in the ar array error is in ar1 array which is having instance in the method **

is there any workaround of this?
`

```
package graph;

import java.util.*;

public class PrintAllPathUsingDfs {
    static ArrayList<Integer> arr[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
//      int V =s.nextInt();
//      int E =s.nextInt();
        arr = new ArrayList[4];
      //arrays cant be generic in java
      for(int i =0 ; i< 4;i++)
      {
          arr[i]=new ArrayList<Integer>();
      }
      arr[0].add(1); 
      arr[0].add(2); 
      arr[0].add(3); 
      arr[2].add(0); 
      arr[2].add(1); 
      arr[1].add(3); 
     int src = 2;
     int d =3;
      ArrayList<Integer> ar=new ArrayList<Integer>();
     printAllPaths(src, d,ar);
 }
    static void printpath(ArrayList<Integer> ar)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<ar.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ar.get(i)+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    static  void printAllPaths(int s , int d,ArrayList<Integer> ar)
    {
       Iterator<Integer> it = arr[s].listIterator();
       ArrayList<Integer> ar1=new ArrayList<>();

//       for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++)
//       {
//         ar1.add(ar.get(i));
//       }
       ar1.add(0);// this adds works
       ar1.add(s);// but this is not working throw error 
      if(d==ar.get(ar.size()-1))
      {
          printpath(ar);
      }
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            printAllPaths(it.next(),d,ar);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: From doc: `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())`

Comment: @KunLun that piece of javadoc is for the get method, not for the add. I doubt the code above is throwing that exception, at the line with the comment though. Most likely on the line after that, on the get indeed.

Comment: @burm87 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-

Comment: @KunLun but it is not that add function, it is this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-
I think @ burm87 is correct.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry

Comment: @KunLun Exactly. The code above is not throwing on the add as stated I reckon, but on the get.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], because we can't really tell that the exception you're seeing is really occuring

Comment: Can you give us some inputs for this method which reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error probably occurs at `ar.get(ar.size()-1)`

Check `ar` size before trying to get the element.

If size is `0`, then `outOfIndex` will occur.

```
if(!ar.isEmpty() && d == ar.get(ar.size()-1)) {
  printpath(ar);
}
```

`isEmpty` checks whether `ArrayList` is empty means `size` is `0` or not.

To avoid `out of bound` exception, added `!(not)Empty` check

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the full stacktrace and how you call the method above?

My first guess is that your code is throwing when you are doing `get`, not when you are calling `add`.

Comment: This should probably be only a comment, as it's asking for information and guessing is not really answering

Answer (score 0):

Probability you have commented at the line number for the Exception is wrong. Most chances for the exception would be at next line inside if condition-
Because here you are trying to fetch the value from an array list passing an index of its size -1 (e.i ar.size() -1). On its very first when array is empty the ar.size() return 0 , on that point of time ar.get(-1) will throw an exception e.i **IndexOutOfBoundsException**

**Note : the target index must be in the range of 0 to list size (0 <= index <= list.size())**

add an extra check in **if condition**

```
if(ar.size()>0 && d==ar.get(ar.size()-1)){
        // process
}
```

Or

```
if(!ar.isEmpty() && d==ar.get(ar.size()-1)){
        // process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot post a comment due to low rep, but to add on, I believe ArrayLists do not throw an `OutOfBoundsException` when the `add()` function is called as ArrayLists automatically maintain their capacity (one of the reasons they are popular).

You can also at any time call `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` to ensure that the ArrayList has enough space, minCapacity being the number of empty slots you need. It's nor necessary though.

I'll remove this if it isn't good practice to post here.